# robot_state_publisher

Tags: robot-state-publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a reason why the robot_state_publisher is publishing joints at different time stamps? I'm new to using this system and need some help with it. My launch file is

```
<launch>
    <include file="$(find hokuyo_node)/hokuyo_test.launch"/>
    <node pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="state_publisher" name="rob_st_pub" >
         <param name="publish_frequency" value="2"/>
         <remap from="joint_states" to="al5b_joint_states" />
    </node>
    <param name="use_rep_117" value="true" />
</launch>
```

And the publisher node is publishing at 100 Hz to try and send the data. I've varied both frequencies in case the node publisher could not catch up but that doesn't seem to be the case. Are there extra parameters to set to get the tf to sample all links in the tree at the same time?

**EDIT**: I Attempted publishing and publish_frequency frequencies across the board - I understand this was just the latest attempt.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35427/robot_state_publisher/) by [ocli](https://answers.ros.org/users/2452/ocli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 215 on 2012-05-31

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2012-05-31**:
I don't quite understand your question, but 2 Hz is way too low for the robot state publisher; try something around 100 Hz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `robot_state_publisher` publishes the TF tree whenever a joint state message is received. For non-fixed joints, the time stamps of the TF transforms are set to the joint state message's stamp.

The publish_frequency specifies how often transforms for fixed joints should be published. A rate of 2Hz might be a little small, the default is 50Hz and should be fine. When fixed joint transforms are published, all transforms have the same time stamp (current time + 0.5 seconds).

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-06-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ocli](https://answers.ros.org/users/2452/ocli/) on 2012-06-01**:
thankyou, that makes perfect sense from what results I was seeing. Can I do forward/inverse kinematics from the fixed joint children/parent links (either end of the tree), or just children/parents of revolute joints? Because I'm experiencing an error with the get_ik/get_fk service.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-06-01**:
You can transform from any part of the tree to any other part of the tree as long as they are connected and there is data at that time. But that is not inverse kinematics!

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-06-01**:
I think libraries like KDL should support fixed joints. IK/FK is independent of the robot_state_publisher, it normally works directly on your URDF file. Check this node out: http://ros.org/wiki/arm_kinematics and maybe open a new question.

**Comment by [ocli](https://answers.ros.org/users/2452/ocli/) on 2012-06-01**:
I understand it's not inverse kinematics but I thought maybe the problem was related. Apparently not, I get "forward kinematics failed" every time I request the service using the tutorial, and thought maybe you can't do forward kinematics on fixed joints or some abnormality.

**Comment by [ocli](https://answers.ros.org/users/2452/ocli/) on 2012-06-01**:
p.s. the robot_state_publisher published the transform to transform a laser to pointcloud not IK.

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-06-01**:
Let's move the discussion of IK/FK to the corresponding question. I posted an answer there.